# Android EditText focus issue, wrong EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

EditText is driving us crazy! really!

We have an issue in the login screen for our app. It contains two EditTexts but only the first (Username) gets focussed, by means of the SoftKeyboard does only show up if the username EditText is touched/clicked. 
Once the username EditText has been clicked, and therefore the SoftKeyboard is visible, when then touching/clicking the password EditText it shows focussed (the cursor is blinking in the password EditText) but input from the Keyboard will be inserted in the username EditText.

Now the funny part. We have tried to turn it off and on again, by means of the screen (by pressing the power button), and then, surprise, everything works as expected.

Are we missing something?

We tried quite everything:

- flattened the view hierarchy
- layout with only one linear layout containing views
- focusable, focusable in touch mode
- remove fill viewport from parent ScrollView
- converted Fragments to Activities

We are using Android Design Support Library v23.1.1 and AppCompat Library v23.1.1

[Screenshot of the login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pgpx.png)

LoginFragment.java

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

private LoginButton fbLoginButton;
private EditText etxUsername;
private EditText etxPassword;
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnRegister;
private Button btnRequestPassword;
private ImageView backgroundImage;
private View content;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup   container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        fbLoginButton = (LoginButton) root.findViewById(R.id.fb_login);
        fbLoginButton.setFragment(this);
        content = root.findViewById(R.id.content);
        etxUsername = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.etx_username);
        etxPassword = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.etx_password);
        btnLogin = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(v -> login());
        btnRegister = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(v -> showRegister());
        btnRequestPassword = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_request_password);
        btnRequestPassword.setOnClickListener(v -> requestPassword());
        backgroundImage = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
        return root;
    }
}
```

fragment_login.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent_black">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/login_form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:src="@drawable/login_logo"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_w_user_24"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etx_username"
                        style="@style/AccountManagerEditText.Light"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/username_or_email"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etx_password"
                        android:inputType="text"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_w_password_24"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etx_password"
                        style="@style/AccountManagerEditText.Light"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:hint="@string/password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_request_password"
                style="@style/VLButtonFlat.Light"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                style="@style/VLButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/login"/>


            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="or"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/fb_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_register"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/create_new_account"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
Added styles

```
<resources
xmlns:tools=" http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

<style name="AccountManagerTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/dirty_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/dirty_white</item>
</style>

<style name="AccountManagerEditText.Light" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/AccountManagerTheme</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/dirty_white</item>
</style>

<style name="AccountManagerEditText.Dark" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/AccountManagerTheme.Dark</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/dirty_white</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: forcefully open keyboard on second `EditText`

Comment: can you post styles of those edittexts.

Comment: @Nilesh, tried it:

`etxPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener((v2, hasFocus) -> etxPassword.post(() ->
                ((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                        .showSoftInput(etxPassword, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)));`

and

`etxPassword.setOnClickListener(v1 ->
            etxPassword.post(() ->
                    ((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                            .showSoftInput(etxPassword, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)));`

Comment: both will be triggered but the SoftInput is not showing/focussing on the password EditText. Username EditText works like expected

Comment: Just encountered this same issue. Have you found the cause/fix?

Comment: Has there been a solution to this?  I am out of ideas to fix this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining these two in your layout that is the child of ScrollView:
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"